# openresty: convert int64 to string

Tags: nginx, lua, protocol-buffers, tostring, openresty

I am using openresty/1.7.7.2 with Lua 5.1.4. I am receiving **int64** in request and i have it's **string** format saved in DB (can't change DB schema or request format). I am not able to match both of them.

```
local i = 913034578410143848 --request
local p = "913034578410143848" -- stored in DB
print(p==tostring(i)) -- return false
print(i%10) -- return 0 ..this also doesn't work
```

Is there a way to convert int64 to string and vice versa if possible?

**update:**
I am getting `i` from protobuf object. proto file describe `i` as int64. I am using `pb4lua` library for protobuf.

```
ngx.req.read_body()
local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
local request, err = Request:load(body)
local i = request.id
```

Comment: In Lua 5.1 after the assignment `local i = 913034578410143848` the variable `i` will contain only approximation of the value `913034578410143848`, not the value exactly.  To work with 64-bit numbers on Lua side, you should read and store them as strings, not as numbers.

Comment: i am getting this value from a protobuf object that is mentioned as int64.

Answer (score 2):

Lua 5.1 can not represent integer values larger than 2^53.
Number literal not excaption. So you can not just write
`local i = 913034578410143848`.
But LuaJIT can represent int64 values like boxed values.
Also there exists Lua libraries to make deal with large numbers. 
E.g. `bn` library.
I do not know how your pb4lua handle this problem.
E.g. `lua-pb` library uses LuaJIT [boxed values](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-pb/blob/master/pb.lua#L62).
Also it provide way to specify user defined callback to make int64 value.
First I suggest figure out what real type of your `i` value (use `type` function).
All other really depends on it.
If its `number` then I think pb4lua just loose some info.
May be it just returns `string` type so you can just compare it as string.
If it provide LuaJIT cdata then this is basic function to convert string 
to int64 value.

```
local function to_jit_uint64(str)
  local v = tonumber(string.sub(str, 1, 9))
  v = ffi.new('uint64_t', v)
  if #str > 9 then
    str = string.sub(str, 10)
    v = v * (10 ^ #str) + tonumber(str)
  end
  return v
end
```